# Forward declaration outside class works, but not when nested

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, pimpl-idiom

Suppose I have two classes `A` and `B` employing the `pimpl` idiom. `A` provides the public API, holding a pointer to `B`. I get a compilation error when forward-declaring `B` within `A`, but not when declaring it outside.

Why would the latter not work? In both cases I am including `b.hpp` within `a.cpp` before calling any methods of `B`.

## Forward declaration outside class `A`

This example works normally.

File `a.hpp`:

```
#ifndef _A_
#define _A_

#include <memory>

class B; // forward declaration, defined in a.cpp
class A {
public:
        A();
        ~A();
        void Hi();
private:
        std::unique_ptr< B > b_;
};

#endif
```

File `a.cpp`:

```
#include "b.hpp"
#include "a.hpp"

A::A() : b_( std::make_unique< B >() ) { }
A::~A() { }

void
A::Hi() {
        this->b_->Hi();
}
```

File `b.hpp`:

```
#ifndef _B_
#define _B_

class B {
public:
        void Hi();
};

#endif
```

File `b.cpp`:

```
#include "b.hpp"

#include <iostream>

void
B::Hi() {
        std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Driver file `hello.cpp`:

```
#include "a.hpp"

int main() {
        A a;
        a.Hi();
        return 0;
}
```

Compiling: `g++ hello.cpp a.cpp b.cpp -std=c++14`

## Forward declaration inside class `A`

Here I am moving the forward declaration of `B` within `A`.

File `a.hpp`:

```
#ifndef _A_
#define _A_

#include <memory>

class A {
public:
        A();
        ~A();
        void Hi();
private:
        class B; // forward declaration, defined in a.cpp
        std::unique_ptr< B > b_;
};

#endif
```

I receive the following compilation errors:

```
a.cpp: In member function ‘void A::Hi()’:
a.cpp:9:10: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class A::B’
  this->b_->Hi();
          ^
In file included from a.cpp:2:0:
a.hpp:12:8: error: forward declaration of ‘class A::B’
  class B;
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:81:0,
                 from a.hpp:4,
                 from a.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object std::make_unique(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = A::B; _Args = {}; typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object = std::unique_ptr<A::B>]’:
a.cpp:4:36:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h:765:69: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class A::B’
     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
                                                                     ^
In file included from a.cpp:2:0:
a.hpp:12:8: error: forward declaration of ‘class A::B’
  class B;
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:81:0,
                 from a.hpp:4,
                 from a.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = A::B]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h:236:16:   required from ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = A::B; _Dp = std::default_delete<A::B>]’
a.cpp:4:36:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h:74:22: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘A::B’
  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
```

Comment: The second example forward-declares class `A::B`, which is distinct from and unrelated to class `::B`. The former is used but never defined. The latter is defined but never used. See also: [nested classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are not declaring the same `class B`. `B` in your second example is declared as a *nested class*. It has the scope `A::` (as in it is actually named class `A::B`). But then you try to use it as `::B` (as in global scope).

This is quite apparant from the error message:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘**class A::B**’

This cannot work. Forward declaring `class B` external to `A` is the correct way to implement this.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now. I was declaring another class, indeed.